# How can I split results into individual hours

Tags: sql, db2

I need this query to have hour as an individual column and a tally the amount of cases per score band that were generated in that hour. What I get now is a column for date and a column for hour but multiple rows for each hour.

````
SELECT date(s.CREATED_DTTM) as date,
   hour(s.CREATED_DTTM) as hour 
   ,COUNT(score) AS TOTAL                        
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score = 000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       
    AS #000 
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 001 AND 050 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       
    AS #001_TO_050                                                       
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 051 AND 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       
    AS #051_TO_100                                                       
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 101 AND 150 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       
    AS #101_TO_150                                                       
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 151 AND 200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       
    AS #151_TO_200                                                       
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 201 AND 250 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       
    AS #201_TO_250                                                       
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 251 AND 300 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       
    AS #251_TO_300                                                       
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 301 AND 350 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       
    AS #301_TO_350                                                       
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 351 AND 400 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       
    AS #351_TO_400                                                       
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 401 AND 450 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       
    AS #401_TO_450                                                       
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 451 AND 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       
    AS #451_TO_500                                                       
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 501 AND 550 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)       
     AS #501_TO_550                                                    
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 551 AND 600 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    
     AS #551_TO_600                                                    
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 601 AND 650 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    
     AS #601_TO_650                                                    
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 651 AND 700 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    
     AS #651_TO_700                                                    
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 701 AND 750 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    
     AS #701_TO_750                                                    
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 751 AND 800 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    
     AS #751_TO_800                                                    
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 801 AND 850 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     AS #801_TO_850  
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 851 AND 900 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     AS #851_TO_900 
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 901 AND 950 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     AS #901_TO_950 
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 951 AND 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     AS #951_TO_1000 
     ,s.OID,
     CASE s.Type when '1' then 'a1' ELSE 'a2' END as "TYPE"
     FROM Schema.Table 1 s, Schema.Table 2 c                                             
     WHERE s.CREATED_DTTM >= '2022-03-01-00.00.00.000001' 
     AND  s.CREATED_DTTM <  '2022-03-02-00.00.00.000000' 
     and s.ID = c.ID
     and s.OID = 'OID'
     GROUP BY  s.Type, s.OID,  date(s.CREATED_DTTM), hour(s.CREATED_DTTM), s.ID
     ORDER BY  date(s.CREATED_DTTM) desc, hour(s.CREATED_DTTM) desc
     WITH UR;
     ```
````

This is a small section of the result set I will get from the above query; but, as you can see, I have multiple entries for the 23rd hour of the day(23:00).

```
DATE       HOUR TOTAL   #000    #001_TO_050     #051_TO_100     #101_TO_150    OID    TYPE
2022-03-01  23    1       0          0               1               0          1       a1
2022-03-01  23    1       0          0               0               0          1       a2
2022-03-01  23    1       0          0               0               0          1       a2
2022-03-01  23    1       0          0               0               0          2       a1
2022-03-01  23    1       0          0               0               0          1       a1
```

Comment: By using `GROUP BY  s.Type, s.OID,  date(s.CREATED_DTTM), hour(s.CREATED_DTTM), s.ID` you tell that you want a row for each distinct tuple of five value. Add `s.Type, s.OID, s.ID` to your select and you will see those which should'nt be there.

Comment: I'm not sure in understand what that is changing? I have those fields in the select statement already at the bottom, I need it to show the total volumes of cases generated in each of the score bands for each hour.

Comment: I mean run your query with `SELECT s.Type, s.OID, s.ID, date(s.C...` you will probably see a distict value for s.ID for each row.

Comment: I understand what you mean but that still presents as individual rows as like you said they are all unique values, the s.ID is only used as a key to join the two tables in this query. I need it to tally up the distinct cases based on score band and hour.

I have all the data it just needs to be formatted in such a way that there is 2 rows for each hour, one for each of the types.

Comment: Not sure whether the SQL you posted is the one you are running. s.number is not in group by. Also, output shows 1,2 for Type, type should be a1,a2 based on SQL

Comment: Its not the correct SQL no, I have had to get rid of some stuff due to it being work related.  Number should have been type. and I have corrected the example of the output.

Apologies first time poster :)

Comment: So if you don't need to have a row for each s.id, remove it from group by

Comment: I cant believe I didn't see that, in my defense this isn't my query! Thanks for your patients and help people! :)

Comment: If you have more than 2 values (1,2,3,...) for type, you will still get multiple rows for date, hour and type ("a2") due to case statement for type